# Is a number devided by two different sizes of infinite is equal?

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, infinity

Let x be any number,
Is $x / \aleph_0 = x / \aleph_1 = 0$?
Does the size of the infinity matter?
Thanks.

Comment: You would have to tell us how you define those operations.

Comment: Any number? The Aleph numbers are numbers in the sense of cardinal: how do you divide cardinals?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format the formulas in your MSE posts. It is easy to learn and makes your posts much more readable. I have edited your post to use MathJax: have a look (using the Edit button) to see what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you need to define the division operation you are talking about. The only reasonable definition of division for cardinal numbers that I can think of would put:
$$
\frac{\kappa}{\mu} = \sup \{ \alpha \mid \alpha\mu \le \kappa\}
$$

with the proviso that $\mu \neq 0$. Here $\alpha$ ranges over cardinals and $\alpha\mu$ is cardinal multiplication: $\alpha\mu = |\alpha \times \mu|$ (the cardinal of the cartesian product).
This agrees with division with rounding down for finite cardinals. It is not very interesting for infinite cardinals: for infinite $\kappa$ and $\mu$ we will have

$$
\frac{\kappa}{\mu} = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0 & \mbox{if $\kappa < \mu$}\\
\kappa & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: I don’t know much about cardinal arithmetic but I think for infinite $\kappa<\mu$, $\kappa\mu=\max(\kappa,\mu)=\mu$, so surely the division is at least $\kappa$.

Comment: @FShrike: thanks:  I got $\kappa$ and $\mu$ the wrong way round in the set comprehension. I've fixed that. Does it make sense now?

Comment: It makes sense to me now, insofar as I am very illiterate in set theory!

Comment: Indeed on that note I might ask you to give a rough hint as to why the division splits like that in the infinite case. It is clearly $0$ if $\mu>\kappa$, but why is it always $\kappa$ if $\kappa\ge\mu$?

Comment: Hm. Would it also be possible to define division of cardinals in a manner analogous to taking quotient objects [groups/rings/whatever], the cardinality of “how many copies” you need of $\mu$ to cover the set $\kappa$?

Comment: @FShrike. For your comment beginning "Indeed": for an infinite $\kappa$, it can be shown that $\kappa^2 = \kappa$, so $\kappa\mu \le \kappa$ for any $\mu \le \kappa$. For your comment beginning "Hm":  your suggestion is identical with mine if you unwind the definitions of cardinal multiplication and the ordering relation on cardinals.

Comment: $\frac{\kappa}{\kappa}=\kappa$ is slightly interesting for infinite cardinals $\kappa$ since it is not true for finite cardinals $>1$

Comment: @Henry: perhaps I should have said "not so diverse" rather than "not so interesting". It certainly is interesting that $\kappa^2 = \kappa$ for infinite $\kappa$.